# My case class contains a property of type Any, how do I create an implicit for Any?

Tags: scala, reactivemongo

I have a case class like:

```
case class House(id: Int, name: String, meta: Any)
```

I get this compile error:

```
implicit not found for 'House.value': reactivemongo.api.bson.BSONReader[Any]
```

I tried creating a custom BSONReader like:

```
 implicit object anyBSONReader extends BSONReader[Any] {
    override def readTry(bson: BSONValue): Try[Any] = bson.asTry[Any].map(v => v.asInstanceOf[Any]).toOption
  }
```

I then imported this anyBSONReader that like this:

```
case class House(id: Int, name: String, meta: Any)
object House {
    implicit object anyBSONReader extends BSONReader[Any] {
        override def readTry(bson: BSONValue): Try[Any] = bson.asTry[Any].map(v =>  
            v.asInstanceOf[Any])
 }
   implicit val houseHander = Macros.hander[House]
}
```

I still get the same error message

Comment: You don't want to use an `Any` never. What if I create a `House(id = 0, name = "foo", meta = dbConnection)` how are you going to save in the database a database connection? Or a file? or an HTTP request?

Comment: I see what your saying, but having said that, how would I go about writing the reactivemongo handler for this situation?

Comment: Avoiding the situation at all. You almost never want to have a value of type `Any` - Rather, explain the meta-problem you are trying to solve using that `Any`